# Stains removal and solutions

Tags: steel

Is there any way to get a solution for stains like this [image]

Comment: this looks like rust to me.you can get it scraped and then get it painted

Answer (score 1):

If you own a grinder use a wire wheel attachment like this one:

[image]

and make sure you use gloves and eye protection. And then clean the area with a paint thinner. And then paint your item with metal bearing paint.